# Error with Event ID : 1108 due to Event ID : 4688

Tags: windows, logging, events, event-viewer, eventlog-source

The event logging service encountered an error while processing an incoming event published from Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing.

None of my process creation event is being logged. All these logs are thrown as event 1108 with error code 15003 and 15005. Don't know what to do. Please help me fix this issue.

[image: Error Event ID : 1108 with Error Code : 15005 Source : Eventlog]

[image: Error Event ID : 1108 with Error Code : 15003 Source : Eventlog]

I want to fix the error and the auditing of Process Creation needs to be audited without any error.

Tried many things but couldn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and saw that you asked this question in multiple forums.
I was able to resolve the error. All I did was to install the latest windows updates. Please check if you have any updates available and install them.
It was this update that fixed my issue:

2022-11 Cumulative Update for Windows 11 Version 22H2 for x64-based Systems (KB5020044)